# singleton class in NPM dependencies management

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a doubt about singleton in NPM dependencies management.

Here is my dependency tree:

```
- YoutubeScraper
  - ScrapperFoundation
  - YoutubeScraperCore
    - ScrapperFoundation
```

ScrapperFoundation contains a singleton class 'ScrapperDataService' that both packages 'YoutubeScraper' and 'YoutubeScraperCore' are using.

I'm wondering if that is two instances of 'ScrapperDataService'?

If yes, what would be good practice to achieve global singleton in such setup?

Comment: IIUC node.js will `require()` the module only once, and webpack will create a single instance of the module, so these optimizations would accidentally bring about the behavior you're looking for. If you want to be explicit, you can put the singleton's data in the `global` or `window` object.

Comment: after I did npm dedupe, it works for me because 'ScrapperDataService' is a stateful object that i'm exporting and 2nd library could see changes made from 1st pkg. React-native metro bundler(which i'm using) seems not doing this automatically for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a global singleton class like this,

**ScrapperFoundation.js**

```js
let instance = null;

class ScrapperDataService {

    constructor() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = this;
        }
        return this;
    }
}

export default ScrapperDataService;
```

**Usage**

```js
import ScrapperDataService from './ScrapperFoundation'

new ScrapperDataService();
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think it is valid if using different versions of 2 packages there will be 2 instances event with the condition